# Django: Retrieving tweets followed by current user

Tags: sql, django, django-models

I currently have the following Models set up

`User` Model

```py
class User(AbstractUser):
    pass
```

`Follower` Model

```py
class Follower(models.Model):
    # user is following userFollowing
    user = models.IntegerField()
    userFollowing = models.IntegerField()
```

`Tweet` Model

```py
class Tweet(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="tweets")
    content = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    likes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

I want to get a `QuerySet` of `Tweet`s consisting of `Tweet`s from `User`s that the current user follows.

I managed to get the following but I'm not sure if there's a better way to write the Query

```py
# Retrieve all users followed by current user
usersFollowedByCurrentUser = Follower.objects.all().filter(user=request.user.id)

# Retrieve all Tweets
tweets = Tweet.objects.all().filter(user_id__in=Subquery(usersFollowedByCurrentUser.values('userFollowing')))
```

In summary, I'm trying to execute the following SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM Tweet WHERE user IN (SELECT 1 FROM Follower WHERE userFollowing = request.user.id)
```

Appreciate any feedback/advice

Answer (score 1):

your approach is fine.

You can try this also untested code.

```
tweets = Tweet.objects.filter(user__in=usersFollowedByCurrentUser).select_related('user')
```